# export certificate from IE to use with wget

Tags: certificate, wget

I am trying to access an internal corporate web-site that is available with client certificate only using `wget`, `curl` or similar. I can access this site with IE and Chrome.

How do I export a certificate from `IE` and use it with `wget`?

I have so far tried the following without luck

- Export from IE without private key in `der` format and use it with `wget --certificate-type=DER`
- Export from IE with private key in `pfx` and use it with and without `--certificate-type=DER`
- Export from IE as above and convert to `pem` using the command `openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -out cert.pem -nodes` and use it without `--certificate-type=DER`

Answer (score 1):

You MUST have the matching private key in order to use a client cert to authenticate to a server. Presenting a cert without the matching private key is like a presenting a username without a password. Anyone could know your username, or have made a copy of your cert. It doesn't prove that you're *you*, so it can't be used for authentication. Just like knowing your password proves that you're the owner of a certain username, the private key is the secret that only you know, that proves that you're the proper owner of the certificate.

So you need to export both the certificate and the matching private key one way or another, and get them both into DER or PEM format, and give them both to `wget` via the appropriate command-line arguments.

I don't see a way to pass `wget` an encryption password for your private key, which totally sucks, because it means you'll have to leave your private key unencrypted on disk, which is a big no-no. Secrets are always supposed to be "encrypted at rest" (i.e. when on disk), as well as "encrypted in transit" (i.e. across the network).

It looks like `curl` is better than `wget` on this aspect, because `curl` has the
`-E, --cert <certificate[:password]>` option, so you can keep your private key encrypted on disk. `curl` also seems to have some options for leaving your private key inside keychains on some platforms.

Comment: Thank you so much for a very clear explanation. Especially about private key -- I sort of realized the private key is required but thanks to you now I know why.

While `wget` requires private key as an unencrypted file I am fine with it, I can generally store only the .pfx file containing the private key and extract it into a file giving the password before calling the wget and delete it afterwards. Can you please tell me from the .pfx file how to extract the certificate in der format and extract the private key into a separate file?